# VBA Variant Spreadsheet Update Issue

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

The task I'm trying to complete is comparing a value (e.g. A3) to another value from a different Workbook (A2) and then updating a cell in the first workbook accordingly ("Same" or "Change")

This task is achieved very easily by changing the value I would like to have "Same" or "Change" to

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A1,'[Workbook2.csv]Workbook2'!$A$2:$B$482,2,FALSE)=A1,"Same","Change")
```

In Workbook1

However, I need other tasks to be completed with that information and the values to be changed in different scenarios so I would like to port this functionality to VBA.

This is what I currently have:

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Dim answer As Integer

Dim MyFile As String
MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If (MyFile <> "False") Then


strRangeToCheck = "A2:P527"
Debug.Print Now
varSheetA = Worksheets(3).Range(strRangeToCheck)

' Switch active Workbook
Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
varSheetB = Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck) ' or whatever your other sheet is.
Debug.Print Now
iCol = 1

For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandle:

        NameValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(varSheetA(iRow, iCol), Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck), 1, False)
        StatusValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(varSheetA(iRow, iCol), Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck), 2, False)
        MsgBox NameValue & " " & StatusValue ' Debug

        If varSheetA(iRow, 3) = StatusValue Then
            varSheetA(iRow, 2) = "Same"
        Else
            varSheetA(iRow, 2) = "Change"
        End If

        Next iRow
 Error Handle:
' Generic for now, will be updated later
    Exit Sub

Else
' Else will be put here
End If

End Sub
```

The program works fine up until when varSheetA(iRow, 2) needs to be updated to either "Same" or "Change". It looks like the variables are being updated - however not being returned to the original worksheet.

Does anyone know how I can have these updates show back to the original Workbook?

When this Module runs, Workbook2 remains the Active Worksheet on the screen. I'm not sure if this has any impact on having the values update to Workbook1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out why the sheet wasn't updating, it's not pretty at the moment and I'll probably clean up a lot of the code that isn't necessary for the final release.
Notice the use of SelRangeA  and SelRangeB, rather than using `Variant` type variables, they use `Range` type values.

In order to use `For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)` I needed an array of the cells which is when I used the varSheets.

And when I am updating the values I now use the SelRanges so that it directly updates the sheets rather than updating the values in a variable that never makes it back to my original sheet.

```
    Dim varSheetA As Variant
    Dim varSheetB As Variant
    Dim SelRangeA As Range                             '''''
    Dim SelRangeB As Range                             '''''

Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Dim answer As Long
Dim MyFile As String
Dim WbOne As Workbook 'original WB
Dim WbTwo As Workbook

MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If (MyFile <> "False") Then

Set WbOne = ThisWorkbook
strRangeToCheck = "A2:P527"
Debug.Print Now
varSheetA = Worksheets(3).Range(strRangeToCheck)

Set SelRangeA = Worksheets(3).Range(strRangeToCheck)    '''''

' Switch active Workbook
Set WbTwo = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)
varSheetB = Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck)

Set SelRangeB = Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck)    '''''

Debug.Print Now
iCol = 1

For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandle:

        NameValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SelRangeA(iRow, iCol), Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck), 1, False)
        StatusValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SelRangeA(iRow, iCol), Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck), 2, False)
        'MsgBox NameValue & " " & StatusValue ' Debug

        If SelRangeA(iRow, 3) = StatusValue Then
            SelRangeA(iRow, 2) = "Same"
            Else
                SelRangeA(iRow, 2) = "Change"
            End If

            'ElseIf (1 = 1) Then

            'Else

            'End If

            'If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
                ' Cells are identical.
                ' Do nothing.
            'Else
                ' Cells are different.
                ' Code goes here for whatever it is you want to do.
            'End If
            Next iRow
```

Thanks to [Sgdva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3221380/sgdva) for suggesting the use of WbOne and WbTwo and replacing depreciated variable types, definitely made the code cleaner and easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the WBs to avoid active stuff miss leads

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Dim answer As Long 'integer is "depracated" you may google or look here in S.O
Dim MyFile As String
Dim WbOne As Workbook 'original WB
Dim WbTwo As Workbook

MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If (MyFile <> "False") Then

Set WbOne = ThisWorkbook
strRangeToCheck = "A2:P527"
Debug.Print Now
varSheetA = Worksheets(3).Range(strRangeToCheck)

' Switch active Workbook
Set WbTwo = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)
varSheetB = Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck) ' or whatever your other sheet is.
Debug.Print Now
iCol = 1

For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandle:

        NameValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(varSheetA(iRow, iCol), Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck), 1, False)
        StatusValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(varSheetA(iRow, iCol), Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck), 2, False)
        MsgBox NameValue & " " & StatusValue ' Debug

        If WbOne.Range(varSheetA(iRow, 3).Address) = StatusValue Then
            varSheetA(iRow, 2) = "Same"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had to change `If WbOne.Range(varSheetA(iRow, 3).Address) = StatusValue Then` back to `If varSheetA(iRow, 3) = StatusValue Then` for it to grab the value correctly to make the comparison. I seem to be running into the same problem as before however which is that the values aren't updating in the Workbook. I'm going to try using the WbOne and wbTwo variables you suggested to refer to the cells I'm wanting to update - will let you know if that works.